# Website Deployment

Tags: c#

I have a ready website which is developed by me in ASP.NET with SQL Server 2005 database connectivity.
I want to know that how I can deploy my website on the internet and for this purpose which website I can access.?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to find a hosting provider that offers Windows hosting plans with ASP and SQL Server options.  You'll also need to register a domain name with which to access the site - the hosting provider should be able to help with this too.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1.** Register your Domain.

**Step 2.** Consult hosting provider for web application hosting & other services needed by 
        your application. (For example - Version of .NET Framework, MS-SQL server database, 
        mail, ftp etc)

**Step 3.** Deploy your application.